# ¿Como usar client_id,client_secret passport en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api, tokens, passport

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con laravel 10 y Angular, seguí un un tutorial para realizar dicha sincronizacion con ambos utilizando auth2 con laravel passport.

1.- Me quedo la duda de como utilizar exactamente el client_id y secret_passport, ¿si tengo que enviar dichos parametros siempre realize una petición?.

2.-Al usar el personal access token se que es para la autentificación del usuario y pueda usar la aplicacion ya que se envia este token al hacer la peticion, entonces ¿El token que se envia ya esta validado por decirlo asi con las credenciales del client_id y secret_passport?.